# Why haven't I seen the Havinenu prayer in Sidurs?

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book

I was reviewing recently Rambam's laws of prayers and ran across this 
( [הלכות תפילה פרק ב,ב](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2202.htm#2) ):

> בכל תפילה משלוש תפילות אלו שבכל יום, מתפלל אדם תשע עשרה ברכות אלו על
>   הסדר.  במה דברים אמורים, בשמצא דעתו מכוונת ולשונו תמהר לקרות; אבל אם
>   היה טרוד ודחוק, או שקצרה לשונו--מתפלל שלוש ראשונות וברכה אחת מעין כל
>   האמצעייות ושלוש אחרונות, ויצא ידי חובתו.
>
> ג  וזו היא הברכה שתיקנו מעין כל האמצעייות:  הביננו ה' אלוהינו לדעת
>   דרכיך, ומול את לבבנו ליראתך, לסולח היה לנו, להיות גאולים, רחקנו
>   ממכאוב, ודשננו ושכננו בנאות ארצך, ונפוצים מארבע תקבץ, והתועים בדעתך
>   יישפטו, ועל הרשעים תניף ידך, וישמחו צדיקים בבניין עירך ובתיקון היכלך,
>   ובהצמחת קרן לדויד עבדך ובעריכת נר לבן ישי משיחך; טרם נקרא ואתה תענה,
>   טרם נדבר ואתה תשמע, כי אתה הוא עונה בכל עת צרה, פודה ומציל מכל צוקה. 
>   ברוך אתה ה', שומע התפילה.

Basically, if someone is distracted or has trouble pronouncing the prayers or is extremely pressed for time, he skips the middle thirteen brachot in Amidah, and substitutes the above Havinenu bracha.   But I don't think I've ever noticed the prayer in any siddur, and no one ever told me about it.  Did I just miss it or is it really not there?  If it's really not there, why?

Comment: Ive seen it in siddurim. Not so often though

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes The updated Koren siddur for edot hamizrach (2012) does have it, pg. 851, in addition to an even shorter 3-sentence prayer for even more pressing times (i.e., a soldier at the frontline).

Comment: It's in this one http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34229&st=&pgnum=119

Comment: The Rosh on Brachot Chapter 4, Tur Orach Chaim 110, and Jerusalem Talmud 4:3 bring slightly variant texts.

Comment: The Singers used to have it. Not sure if the later editions do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Koren and Rinat Yisrael siddurim do include it, and possibly others as well.

The Halacha is like Rabbi Akiva in [Mishna Brachot 4:3](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berakhot.4.3). There, he says that one whose davening is not "שגורה בפיו" should say Havineinu. However, in the modern day where everyone can read the entire text from a siddur, we are generally considered as people who are proficient.

This is what i learned doing this Mishna.

Comment: In the 2008 (nusach Ashkenaz) it is right after Shmoneh Esrei, but in the 2011 edition, it is towards the back, after bentching. See if it's over there.

Comment: It actually is in my siddur on page 85 in a tiny little section titled תפילות קצרות in between shacharit and mincha.  It's three pages and has the thirteen principles, ten remembrances and havinenu.

Comment: Do you recall from whom (or from what commentary) you learned this while learning this _mishna_?

Comment: @msh210 It might have been in Kehati.

Comment: Rambam, Tur, Shulchan Aruch, Levush, Aruch Hashulchan (i.e. all the major codes) discuss instances where one can use the Havineinu prayer.

Answer (score 1):

The Birnbaum Siddur Ashkenaz has it right after the weekday Shacharit. The siddur is out of print, but you may be able to obtain a copy via Amazon, eBay and some Judaica stores. It seems that many Conservative / traditional shuls like Birnbaum.

I have seen this in some other Siddurim (offhand, I don't think Art Scroll has it, though) but I have to research a bit.

I don't know much about what's in Nusach Sefard siddurim.

Answer (score 1):

KOREN Ashkenaz, 2009, page 1005.

Answer (score 1):

The Kaf HaChaim 110:5 recommends never saying it, because there are many different Girsaot, in addition to the fact that one can't say it during the rainy season or on days with special insertions. See Orach Chaim 110:1 and commentaries

Comment: There are also many Girsaot of the full Shmoneh Esrei. Probably more in fact. Why not use the same argument to abolish Shmoneh Esrei?

Comment: The Rashba (Berachot 11a) argues Nuschaot not mentioned in Shas aren't me'akev. In hachi nami, Poskim discuss whether one can pray a nussach other than his own traditional one by your logic.